# Android: Cannot get a StateList drawable to work

Tags: android, android-resources

I'm trying to make a state list drawable to be used as a background for an image button.

I'm using these PNG files[image]
[image]

and my state list selector is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/play_button_pressed" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/play_button_pressed" android:state_focused="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/play_button_normal" />
</selector>
```

and the image button is like this:

```
<ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/play_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/play_button_bg"
            />
```

but the button appears as it's having the large image and the background, when clicking on it nothing happens. what can be wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I managed to resolve it using a state list selector with layer lists like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <layer-list>
            <item>
                <bitmap android:src="@drawable/play_button_pressed" android:gravity="center" />
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>
    <item android:state_focused="true">
        <layer-list>
            <item>
                <bitmap android:src="@drawable/play_button_pressed" android:gravity="center" />
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/play_button_normal" />
</selector>
```

The trick is in the bitmap's:
**android:gravity="center"**

Answer (score 1):

change it to:

```
<ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/play_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:src="@drawable/play_button_bg"
        android:background="@null"/>
```

backgrounds by default stretch to fit the view. So the two buttons are being changed, by the final looks is exactly the same.

Using as source and scaling them as "center without scaling", should show the two buttons changing (although the final effect might not be exact what u expect).

As a general rule state drawables gives less headache if all the drawables have the same size.

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue with code. Since both images are identical, it looks like no change when we click on the image button. Change one image to some other png, say a pause button image & try. Also use ImageView in place of ImageButton.